# Getting node metadata in Kendo for Angular TreeView

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

[In this plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/AtVPuTYRMnFj2X0Nj5GR?p=preview) I have a Kendo for Angular TreeView. I added a `value` field to the tree structure and also a `click` event to the nodes. What I need is to get in the console the value of the node clicked. How can that be achieved?

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <kendo-treeview
        [nodes]="data"
        textField="text"
        kendoTreeViewExpandable
        kendoTreeViewSelectable
        kendoTreeViewHierarchyBinding
        childrenField="items"
        (click)="showClick($event)"
    >
    </kendo-treeview>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {

    showClick(event){
      console.log(event);
    }

    public data: any[] = [
        {
            text: 'Furniture', value: "0", items: [
                { text: 'Tables & Chairs', value: "10" },
                { text: 'Sofas', value: "11" },
                { text: 'Occasional Furniture', value: "12" }
            ]
        },
        {
            text: 'Decor', value: "0", items: [
                { text: 'Bed Linen', value: "13" },
                { text: 'Curtains & Blinds', value: "14" },
                { text: 'Carpets', value: "15" }
            ]
        }
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the treeview [selectionChange](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/treeview/api/TreeViewComponent/#toc-selectionchange) event:

```
<kendo-treeview
    ...
    (selectionChange)="showClick($event)"
>
</kendo-treeview>


showClick(event){
  console.log(event.dataItem.value);
}
```

It seems to be triggered on click and contains the clicked node dataItem:
https://plnkr.co/edit/tcUxkkVExZSuEGGSWfia?p=preview